# List Item Attachment Folder Hierarchy

Tags: 2013, list, attachments

Looking to implement a default folder structure for attachments to custom list items.

I haven't really seen anything that would indicate that list item attachments can be organized like this out of the box, so I've considered setting up a document library to hold the attachments, but it feels like a lot of custom connections to manage attachments if I go down this route.

Anyone know of a way to add a folder hierarchy to list attachments to provide structure?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Attachments cannot have a hierarchy.

Assuming you have list data that you want to track, the best approach is to define those data elements as Site Columns, arrange the columns into a Site Content Type (which inherits from Document) and add the content type to a document library.